# Display an XML child element information based on its unique ID

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, coldfusion, hyperlink

I have an XML file that stores movies and their actors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name>Bob</name>
            <age>23</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name>Jack</name> 
            <age>25</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="3"> 
            <name>James</name>
            <age>38</age>
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name>Mike</name>
            <age>19</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name>Daniel</name>
            <age>29</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="3"> 
            <name>Phil</name> 
            <age>41</age>
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

</movies>
```

As you can see from the code above, I have 2 "movie" elements that contain 3 "actor" child elements. Each "movieID" is unique, and each "actorID" is unique within its corresponding "movieID" parent element.

This is my XSLT code that displays actors' names in a list from both movies:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie/actors/actor/name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:element name="a">
          <xsl:attribute name="href">actor_details.cfm?actorID=<xsl:value-of select="../@actorID"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

All 6 actors' names are hyperlinked to actor_details.cfm page based on their corresponding "ActorID".

This is my actor_details.cfm code:

```
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("movies.xml")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xmlInput"  file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset MyXslFile = Expandpath("actor_details.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput"  file="#MyXslFile#">

<cfset xslParam = StructNew() >
<cfset xslParam["actorID"] = "#url.actorID#" >

<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput, xslParam )>
<!--- data is output --->
<cfcontent type="text/html" reset="yes">
<cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```

And this is my actor_details.xsl code

```
<xsl:param name="actorID">1</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <title>Actor details</title>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie/actors/actor[@actorID=$actorID]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="actor">
    <xsl:text>Name: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:element name="br"/>
    <xsl:text>Age: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
    <xsl:element name="br"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When I click on any of the 6 actors' names displayed on the page, it takes me to that specific actor_details page that displays the actor's "name and age".
The only problem I have is that there are two actors with ID 1, two actors with ID 2 and two actors with ID 3 located in 2 movies.

So when I click on Bob (actorID="1"), it takes me to that specific actorID details page. But instead of only displaying
Bob information (name and age), it also displays Mike information.

The reason for that is because Mike's details are also related to "actorID="1" except that
it is located inside another movie element. My program cannot distinguish the difference between the same ActorID's located in separate MovieID's. It just displays all the information related to that specific ID.
So no matter whether I click on Bob or Mike (both have actorID="1"), the page displays the information for both Bob and Mike (their names and ages).

This is what the actor_details page displays:

[image: actors page]

This is what I want the actor_details page to display:

[image: actors page 2]

So even though Bob and Mike have the same ActorID's, they are related to different MovieID's, and therefore, I want to display their information separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Either you pass the MovieID as a parameter in your hyperlink:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">actor_details.cfm?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="../../../@movieID"/>&amp;actorID=<xsl:value-of select="../@actorID"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Or, you define unique IDs for each actor (NOT within each movie):

```
 <movie movieID="17">
     <actors>
          <actor actorID="17_1">...</actor>
          <actor actorID="17_2">...</actor>
 ...
```

If you go with the first option, you would have to modify slightly your actor_details.xsl:

```
<xsl:param name="movieID"/>
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie[@movieID=$movieID]/actors/actor[@actorID=$actorID]"/>
```

Comment: The first option looks like a better solution, but for some reason when I click on the actor's name, ColdFusion reports an unexpected error. Would it have something to do with my actor_details.cfm file code? <cfset xslParam = StructNew() >
<cfset xslParam["actorID"] = "#url.actorID#" >

Comment: Sorry, I never used ColdFusion :). Have you tried to add another line to that file, like the one you already have? `<cfset xslParam["movieID"] = "#url.movieID#" >`

Comment: I have fixed the problem by adding <cfset xslParam["movieID"] = "#url.movieID#" > to my CFM file and <xsl:param name="actorID"/> to my XSL file. so everything works fine now. You solution has helped me greatly. thank you so much!